# Search coils in metal finders

Tags: coil, magnetic-flux, metal

I have been looking into some DIY metal detector projects and search coil designs and got confused:

1. Why do most coil designs use thicker wire for TX and thinner wire for RX?
2. Why do some coil designs shield the coil with aluminum foil and ground it?
3. How do some designs use multiple RX coils (without any 3D ability)?

Comment: There are many metal detector designs, please ask about a specific design.

Comment: An educated guess: 1) The TX is sending a high-current pulse. 2) To shield for stray capacitance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why most coil designs use thicker wire for TX and thinner wire for RX?*

Because there may be amps of current circulating in the TX coil. The TX coil is usually made to resonate with a parallel tuning capacitor and amps are the order of the day. In a metal detector I'm currently designing, the TX coil is circulating about 12 amps RMS. Despite the coil taking 12 amps RMS and, having 40 volts p-p across it (14 volts RMS), the 24 volt supply current consumption is less than 60 mA.

More TX coil current = more magnetic field = deeper penetration = better sensitivity = smaller pieces can be detected = happier user.

The RX coil current will be at most milliamps and although it's useful to have low resistance to get a higher Q resonance (= more signal), it isn't as important as it is for the TX coil.

> *Why some coil designs shield the coil with aluminum foil and ground
> it?*

It's to prevent TX coil electric fields creating a "noise" signal on the RX coil due to "ground effect". In other words, a damp ground (a la beach combing detecting) will create a massive receive signal that swamps a real signal from a small piece of metal (poor signal to noise ratio).

> *How some designs use multiple RX coils (without any 3D ability)?*

The more sensitive induction-balance metal detectors (commonly used by detectorists) usually use at least two receive coils hence, the total number of coils is three. I've designed metal detectors that used up to 6 coils (just to get a tad more sensitivity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have seen some DIYers that used thicker wire for RX and got worse results then with thinner one - why is that? theoretically thicker wire = less Ohms= higher Q factor 

about the third question i couldn't really understand how does the sensitivity increase?

Comment: I can't say why thicker wire on the RX coil didn't work well for them; there are many factors to consider. Increasing sensitivity with more coils --> generally two parallel TX coils at a certain spacing will produce a a localized flux on one RX coil that is larger and ditto the other RX coil. There are many factors to consider of course. Have you taken the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) @RonVaisman because I see that you haven't accepted any answers to previous questions.